# Study the convergence and then calculate the improper integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Hoping someone could help me with this.

Study the convergence and then calculate the following improper integral:

$ \int_0^\infty{\frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}}$

I don't really know how to calculate the value of an integral in this form. Anyone might help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your integral as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-x}{2(x^2-x+1)}+\frac{1+x}{2(x^2+x+1)}\right)dx$$
the integrand is the partial fracture decomposition,
$$\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1}=1/2\,{\frac {x+1}{{x}^{2}+x+1}}+1/2\,{\frac {-x+1}{{x}^{2}-x+1}}$$

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did you get to this form?